# How to fix compiler errors after upgrading gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm working on a zlinux machine and we upgraded gcc from v8.2.1 to 8.5.0. The code worked before updating gcc. Since then I'm now getting errors such as below. This is now happening on multiple files. There is no way it's the actual code, since it all worked before upgrading. This is changes due to the upgrade in gcc.

```
Error executing command: g++ src/buffer.cc -c -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wunused -Wno-unused-result -Werror -Wparentheses -DV8_REVERSE_JSARGS -std=c++17 -Wno-register -DUSE_KERBEROS -DUSE_LDAP -pedantic-errors -g   -O3 -I v8 -I v8/include -I openssl/include -I zlib -I snappy/build -I snappy -I brotli/c/include -I openldap/include -I krb5/src/include -I . -o out/s390x.lin.release/obj/buffer.o
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:1935: Error: junk at end of line: `,3'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:10670: Error: junk at end of line: `,3'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:10875: Error: junk at end of line: `,3'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:21852: Error: junk at end of line: `,3'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:21862: Error: junk at end of line: `,3'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:21911: Error: junk at end of line: `,3'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:21912: Error: junk at end of line: `,3'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:22141: Error: junk at end of line: `,3'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:22151: Error: junk at end of line: `,3'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:22200: Error: junk at end of line: `,3'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:22201: Error: junk at end of line: `,3'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:24080: Error: junk at end of line: `,4'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:24084: Error: junk at end of line: `,4'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:25733: Error: junk at end of line: `,4'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:25737: Error: junk at end of line: `,4'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:26008: Error: junk at end of line: `,4'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:26010: Error: junk at end of line: `,4'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:50715: Error: junk at end of line: `,3'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:62134: Error: junk at end of line: `,4'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:62138: Error: junk at end of line: `,4'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:62818: Error: junk at end of line: `,4'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:62819: Error: junk at end of line: `,4'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:62955: Error: junk at end of line: `,4'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:62956: Error: junk at end of line: `,4'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:63039: Error: junk at end of line: `,4'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:63043: Error: junk at end of line: `,4'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:63174: Error: junk at end of line: `,4'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:63175: Error: junk at end of line: `,4'
/tmp/ccClzTUm.s:63716: Error: junk at end of line: `,3'
```

Comment: "I'm unsure of how to fix this." So are we. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I would say look at line 1935 of `/tmp/ccClzTUm.s` and determine why it says ",3" is extra junk. I do agree its odd that gcc is generating output that it thinks is improper.

Comment: It's a long-shot, but when I attempted to introduce clang-format to my company's code base, I discovered a small handful of files with different encodings and it was throwing the tool off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to upgrade binutils. That solved the errors, essentially the assembler needed to be upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error with junk characters at the end of some lines in the generated assembly code.

You probably wanna
Check source code to make sure it works (and compiles on another machine) or try another compiler. If none of this works try going back to the previous version of gcc that u were using.

This is a syntax issue so check your code with the new version of gcc and see if anything changed (it probably didn’t)